# Scheduling table dbo.sysschedules to individual records

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, sql-server-agent

I'm looking for a query to convert records in the dbo.sysschedules table into individual records for each occasion the schedule is expected to run.

For example, a schedule is set to run once every day for the month of August 2012. The query would produce a result with 31 records.

The above is a very simple example, though I am looking for query to cover all scenarios that could occur when creating a schedule.

Is there a query or stored procedure already out there what does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following blog post when looking for my answer:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2008/10/10/Keep-track-of-all-your-jobs-schedules.aspx